# Custom routing logic and serving static content while having the document root in the parent of the public directory?

Tags: zend-framework, url-routing

I extend `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Abstract` in Zend Framework to add custom routing to my application. My `match` method return `false` in cases it identify that the request path isn't ones of the paths it must process. So with paths, like statics resources paths, my custom routing class return `false` and the default Module router take care of.

My problem is that all work fine as far I have the document root of my site pointing to my public directory. When I change the document root to the directory in witch public folder is (parent directory), the following error appear when try to request an static resource like http://mysite.com/css/global.css:

> An error occurred Page not found Exception information:
>
> Message: Invalid controller specified (css) Stack trace:
>   Stack trace: ....
>
> Request Parameters:
>
> ```
>   array (   'controller' => 'css',   'action' => 'global.css',   'module' => 'default', )
> ```

That is just part of the message, the other part is irrelevant.

My questions is, how can I solve this problem? How can I have my custom routing logic and serving static content while having the document root in the parent of the public directory?

Here the .htaccess I uses when document root isn't pointing inside public dir:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ="/" RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php
>   [NC,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
>
> RewriteRule ^/public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

You should not server static files from PHP. It means you should use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This don't work. When I put an .htaccess file with this content in my document root and access http://mysite.com I just get a directory listing. With the .htaccess file I listed I get the correct html, but the problem is that css, js and images don't show because my custom logic routing. I'm not serving statics files, I'm running a Zend Framework application that server static content but that have the particularity to have a custom routing.

Comment: I hoped you would understand, that you obviously need to change the index.php part, but the first part (the -s, -l -d and next line) should make it possble to call /public/css/style.css...